# Why am I getting ActionController::UnknownFormat when sending a file in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**about.html.erb**

```
form_tag({ :action => 'contact_send'}, :format => :js, :multipart => true, :remote => true, :id => "mensaje") do
```

**notifications.rb**

```
class Notifications < ApplicationMailer
   def contact_email(data)
    @data = data
    attachments["#{@data[:name].parameterize}.pdf"] = File.absolute_path(@data[:file].tempfile)
   ....
```

**frontend_controller.rb**

```
def contact_send
  ....
  Notifications::contact_email(@parameters).deliver_now

  respond_to  do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I have a **contact_send.js.erb** which it works when I don't add a file to the form, but get an error in ***respond_to  do |format|*** when the file is sent.

Also the mail is sent with the file using letter_opener so there is no issue in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote true, does an AJAX request. And you can't do multipart while doing AJAX. At least now without a *javascript (jQuery) upload plugin* of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed the issue

```
$("form#mensaje").submit(function(){

       var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

       $.ajax({
          url: '/contact/send',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          async: false,
          success: function (data) {

          },
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
       });

       return false;
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), thanks!